# Can a Philippine passport holder like me (living in Italy) travel to Spain with only Passport and Italian Carta D'identita'?

Tags: schengen, passports, italy, spain, identity-cards

I do have permesso di soggiorno but will only last 2 months, I just got it today 02/03/2021. So i was thinking and very curious to know if I can travel to Spain without permesso di soggiorno but only with Philippine Passport and Italian Carta D'identita'. planning to travel hopefully this year.

Comment: Does the [Carta D'identita](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/ITA-BO-04004/index.html) it contain the text: **NON VALIDA PER L'ESPATRIO** ("not valid for travel abroad")?

Comment: @MarkJohnson i’m not a citizen here in Italy so immigrants like doesn’t have a Carta D’identità valid for expatriation but maybe when I have my passport with me and carta d’identità italiana, i could travel i guess(?)

Comment: Italy issues the Carta D'identita to all residents (including other EU-Citizens). Some expat sites state that for non-Italians it is only valid within Italy, so other EU-Citizens require their national Id or passport when leaving Italy. Thus my question if the these cards have the **NON VALIDA PER L'ESPATRIO** statement in the lower righthand corner. For non EU-Citizens the Schengen Code Article 6 (1)(b) would apply: **except where they hold a valid residence permit or a valid long-stay visa;**, meaning the **residence permit** is required togeather with their passport.

Comment: @MarkJohnson (i still don’t have carta d’identità but i’m about to have) I asked my lawyer if I can request a carta d’identità “valida per l’espatrio” he said only those with italian citizenships and those natives, so by that being said, my soon to have carta d’identità will be valid only here in italy. So I was thinking if i can travel with Passport, Carta D’identità (non valida per l’espatrio) and Permesso di Soggiorno or just with Passport and Carta D’identità.

Comment: Your passport and Permesso di Soggiorno is what you will need to travel to other Schengen member states.